# What is a "grappler item" in tensorflow terminology?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand the "grappler" module located at:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/grappler

Can somebody tell me what is meant by the "grappler item"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Grappler is Tensorflow's optimization module. When a graph is run, it is optimized similar to how a compiler optimizes a program during compilation. According to [the source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/grappler/grappler_item.h), `grappler_item` appears to be an instance of a Tensorflow graph to be optimized:

```
// A TensorFlow model to optimize.
// Models are represented by the combination of a graph, one of more fetch
// nodes, and potentially a set of nodes to feed.
```